# Where to find KB2619234

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2013, knowledge-base

I am struggling to get an Exchange 2013 running on a Windows 2008 R2. Actually I am  following the steps from here: https://www.prajwaldesai.com/how-to-install-exchange-server-2013/ 
Well, the installer really complains about not having kb2619234. But I can't find it anywhere. The official page of that KB (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2619234/a-hotfix-is-available-to-enable-the-association-cookie-guid-that-is-us) contains no any download link. Here (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e413481-0f7a-4995-a59d-276255f1d85b/unable-to-download-hotfix-kb2619234-for-exchange-2013-installation-on-win-2008-r2?forum=exchangesvrdeploy) is an alternate download method, that is also unavailable.

Can somebody give a hint where I could find it?

I ahve found this: http://downloads.landynamix.co.za/Exchange/Exchange%202013/Exchange%202013%20Prerequisites/ , looks ok, but I am a little bit skeptic.

Comment: It has been discontinued. Wouldn't help you anyway if your server has been updated since 2011, because the files in the hotfix were superseded eight years ago.

Comment: @GregAskew Got the point, but I still need to get a test environment up and running with these.

Comment: Are the two files in the patch up to date?

Comment: Strange bug, as even https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/kb2619234-update-not-installed-exchange-2013-help point to that KB, will let you know if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find it, I would post an answer I got from another user in email if that can help;

> I would call the support (1-800-Microsoft) and state that you need
>   that hotfix.
>
> If you state up front what you need, they will not charge you for the
>   call.

Comment: Yeah, that's an option too. Thanks. In the meantime, I have downloaded it from the latest link where there are other prerequisites too. Rigorous scanning did not reveal any malicious code (https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/14264e03954ddab5d5d8e98b0046bf1cab9f99649b04572913aca2ba20fd45f8/analysis/). If I can't find any official source soon, I will give a try with that.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can configure Windows Update to install the latest security updates on your server.

Comment: Sorry, not an option. I need to stay offline. It is a test environment with no internet connection.